# Clojure - Using a variable as a function call

Tags: clojure

I am currently trying to make a simple Clojure macro that applies the inputted function twice: `(f (f args))`, (e.g `(inc (inc 4)) => 6`)

The problem is, when I run the below code using `(reapply-function '(inc 4))`, I get `nil`. This doesn't make sense to me since I can print out both the value of `f` and the result to get `inc` and `5`. There must be a really simple thing I'm missing. Can anyone see the issue?

```
(defmacro reapply-function
  [args]
  (list 'let ['f (list 'first (list 'quote args))
              'result args]
        (list 'f 'result)))
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Initial Note

This answer is provided assuming that you're trying to learn to use macros for its own sake. I fully agree with [@Thumbnail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40451552/14122): Don't use macros except when you absolutely, positively cannot avoid it -- and this is not one of those times.

#### Shorter Implementation

Consider:

```
(defmacro reapply-function [[func & rest]]
  `(~func (~func ~@rest)))
```

`macroexpand` demonstrates how it works:

```
user=> (macroexpand '(reapply-function (inc 4)))
(inc (inc 4))
```

...and it functions in the repl:

```
user=> (reapply-function (inc 4))
6
```

---

#### ...But Why Didn't The Original Work?

With your original implementation, `macroexpand-1` gives us this:

```
(let [f (first (quote (inc 4)))
      result (inc 4)]
  (f result))
```

...which does indeed evaluate to `nil`.

But why? In short: *`f` is, in this code, a **symbol**, not the function that symbol points to*.

Thus, to make the shortest possible change that makes the original code function:

```
(defmacro reapply-function
  [args]
  (list 'let ['f (list 'first (list 'quote args))
              'result args]
        (list '(resolve f) 'result)))
```

Comment: Yea I was getting: `(let*
 [f (first '(inc 5)) result (inc 5)]
 (f result))` when using macroexpand. I'm not sure how to pick out what's wrong with this statement either. But nonetheless, thanks!

Comment: Yup. Because `(first '(inc 5))` is the symbol for `inc`, not the function `inc`.

Comment: That makes sense. So resolve retrieves the value a symbol points to, like println, except it can be used in a function call. Neat, thanks again.

Comment: The "shorter implementation" evaluates `func` twice.  If `func` is provided as a symbol, there's no issue.  But `func` could be any expression that yields a function -- including a very computationally intensive one.  That expression will be evaluated twice.  To fix this, use `gensym` to establish a fresh variable, then bind that variable (via `let`) to the result of the `func` expression.

Answer (score 3):

The first rule of macro club is ... don't use macros unless you have to.

In this case,

```
(defn twice [f]
  (fn [& args] (f (apply f args))))

((twice inc) 4)
;6
```

Or, if you prefer to swallow the function and its arguments at once,

```
(defn reapply-function [f & args]
  (f (apply f args)))

(reapply-function inc 4)
;6
```

---

You can find the rules of *macro club* in [Programming Clojure by Halloway & Bedra](https://pragprog.com/book/shcloj2/programming-clojure). Also, the above rather casts a side-light on the question than answer it.

Comment: Note there is also `iterate`

Comment: @ClojureMostly `(defn re-apply [f x] (nth (iterate f x) 2))` is longer, and doesn't cope with other initial arities for `f`, without which we can simply say `(defn re-apply [f x] (-> x f f))`.